# mysql query error 1064 without apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with some tables. In php script exist this code

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Id='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
```

and it works fine.

Now i add 1 new table and mysql_query get:

> Error #1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO...

The Php script work with this syntax

```
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE Id='".$id."' LIMIT 1
```

Without this symbol `'` script return error message. How can it be, select query to table1 works fine and similar query don't work without `'` symbol around table name?

Comment: Just stop using `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: Are you running second query directly in you `phpmyadmin` or using `php` code you are trying to run it?

Comment: running directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: If you want to run this directly in phpmyadmin, you cannot use the PHP code for that.

Comment: Are you ok, what the hell  `sql` understand about `'".$id."'` if you are running it directly.

Comment: no. in phpmyadmin i use without `'".$id."'`, there was number in query.

Comment: i just want to know, how can it be, similar script run without apostrophe in first query, and return error for second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the table name of your code not table1 and table2. The reson for this error could be that your table name is a "reserved word"

Example:

It works

```
Select * from table1
```

The following example will get error because using of reserved words

```
Select * from update
```

To correct this the word update must be written between apostrophe `

Comment: table name is 'order'. it's reserved word?

Comment: Yes! It is! Order is a mysql command. So you need back ticks (not single quotes as you say)

Comment: It's explain why i get this error. Many thanks!!!

Comment: you are very welcome

Comment: You **really** must read my answer. You're doing a disservice to the entire human race by continuing to write code like this in 2016!

Answer (score 0):

There are a GREAT many problems with your question, and I am very afraid that people will close it because of your extremely poor coding quality rather than use it as a teaching lesson. Here we go!!

## 1. Stop using `mysql_` functions!!

`mysql_` functions have been deprecated for over ***ten years*** now. Using them is beyond negligent. They have been deprecated for at least three years and are no longer present in modern PHP.

Use PDO instead. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

## 2. Stop using SQL injections!! Start using *prepared statements*.

This is why your query is failing.

Implement the selected answer in [**How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/430062)

## 3. Grow your PHP skills.

Your code is of such low quality, you absolutely must start growing *today*. You are only making the Web worse by continuing such practices, and undoubtedly, if you're doing stuff that has been advised, ***strongly***, against for the better part of 12 years, you're doing other ***really bad things*** as well.

So please start learning again, today!